# Print data from a file to a template using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file containing some infos ( A.txt ; sep="\t" ; first column is "\t") :

```
    Well    Fluor   Target  Content Sample  Cq  SQ
    A01 Cy5 EC  Unkn-01 205920777.1 25.714557922167 NaN
    A01 FAM Covid   Unkn-01 205920777.1 21.6541150578409    NaN
    A02 Cy5 EC  Unkn-09 neg5    25.5068289526473    NaN
    A02 FAM Covid   Unkn-09 neg5    NaN NaN 
    A07 Cy5 EC  Unkn-49     NaN NaN
    A07 FAM Covid   Unkn-49     NaN NaN
```

And I have a template (B.txt;sep=",") :

```
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

And I want to put the infos of A.txt in C.txt by using the template B.txt.
C.txt :

```
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
,,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

The trick is to print only line in A.txt that aren't empty for column 5.
I've try things like  :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$5]=$1;next}{print $1,$2,a[$1]} ' A.txt B.txt > C.txt
```

But it can't works because B.txt don't have a similar key. And the difference of separator is also an issue.
Can someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need _one_ `C.txt` file with a line for each entry in `A.txt`? Or many `C.txt` files, one for each entry? Your example has only 2, why? Is there something special about Unkn-01 and Unkn-09? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first column of your file is empty as you say, you need to shift everything one to the left. When you talk about the 5th field, that's actually the 6th. In any case, the simplest approach I can think of is to first modify your `A.txt` file so it has a format you can use:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS="," '(NR>1 && $6!="NaN"){print ",",$6,$2,$5}' A.txt  | sort | uniq 
,,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
,,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
```

That should give you the strings you want to insert into your `C.txt`. So, to add them, you can do something inelegant like this:

```
( head -n 13 B.txt 
  awk -F'\t' -v OFS="," '(NR>1 && $6!="NaN"){print ",",$6,$2,$5}' A.txt | sort | uniq
  tail -n+14 B.txt ) > C.txt
```

Which produces:

```
$ cat C.txt
kit
Software Version =
Date And Time of Export =
Experiment Name =
Instrument Software Version =
Instrument Type = CFX
Instrument Serial Number =
Run Start Date =
Run End Date =
Run Operator =
Batch Status = VALID
Method = Novaprime
Date And Time of Export,Batch ID,Sample Name,Well,Sample Type,Status,Interpretive Result,Action*,Curve analysis
,,205920777.1,A01,Unkn-01
,,neg5,A02,Unkn-09
,,,,,,,,,,
*reporting.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps a lot ! Just one step missing, because I only want one line per sample, not each occurrence.

Comment: @nstatam see updated answer.